# Is it possible to keep dependency between two GCP schedule tasks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dependencies, scheduler

I have gone through the documentation of GCP scheduler but couldn't find a dependency feature in GCP Scheduler. Can someone please suggest if there is any option to keep a dependency between two schedule tasks.

I mean if one schedule task completes successfully then 2nd schedule task should start at scheduled time otherwise skip running 2nd scheduled task.

If there is no dependency feature in GCP schedule, is there any other way to achieve it? I know this can be achieved by using GCP Cloud Composer but is there any other way?

Comment: Is the 2 jobs can be executed sequentially? I mean, is, when the 1st job end in success, the 2nd can start? Or there is a required delay between both?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) triggers work based on time schedules.  That's pretty much its purpose in life.  When the trigger time arrives, it commonly uses either Pub/Sub or HTTP to fire its work.   You didn't paint any details in your story but I'm going to assume that at time T1, job J1 fires.  At time T2, job J2 fires.  You don't want job J2 to fire if job J1 failed.  T2 always starts sufficiently far after T1 ends that there won't be a race.

A first pass at the solution of not firing J2 if J1 fails is to have J1 write its completion status to a datastore such as DataStore or FireStore.  When J2 starts, it could examine the outcome of the last J1 and determine whether or not to proceed.

If you don't want to include this kind of logic in your in your actual code, you could create a front-end piece of logic that is fired by the jobs that performs the guard checking before relaying the request to start to your real logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a cloud scheduler job and cloud tasks combined. Use cloud scheduler to trigger the first job at regular intervals. If the job is successful and needs subsequent processing, then you can create a cloud task to trigger the subsequent processing. I assume you want this to happen at a specific time and that can easily be achieved with cloud tasks by specifying scheduleTime.

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task